# How to connect to open edge data base using .pf file?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl, progress-db, 4gl

I'm new to open edge progress ABL.
How to connect to the open edge database using .pf file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PF file is a simple text file with all relevant database connection parameters, e.g.

```
-db c:\full\path\to\database
```

or

```
-db databasename (no .db)
-H hostname or IP address
-S portnumber or portname
```

Then you start the client with

```
prowin -pf pffile.pf
prowin32 -pf pffile.pf
_progres -pf pffile.pf
```

Comment: Could you please tell me is there a way to get '.r' file from GUI Procedure editor or app builder and not from developer studio

Comment: You have received two answers to your separate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74733273/how-to-get-r-file-without-open-edge-developer-studio/74733586#74733586 - don't use a single thread to ask more than one question.

Answer (score 2):

Create a .pf file, I am calling it connect.pf, containing something similar to:

```
# connect to db using a .pf file
-db dbname
```

along with any other startup parameters that you might desire and then reference the .pf file on your command line or in the properties of your shortcut:

```
mpro -pf connect.pf
```