# How to get '.r' file without open edge developer studio?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I'm new to progress open edge. Is it possible to get a '.r' file using GUI Procedure editor or app builder, if so how to get it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the GUI procedure editor, use the "Application Compiler" from the "Tools" menu.

Or enter the following code in the procedure editor and execute (F2):

```
COMPILE path/to/your.p SAVE.
COMPILE path/to/your.w SAVE.
```

Answer (score 2):

You need some sort of compiler license to generate r-code.

The "showcfg" utility will list the licenses that you have available.

Comment: Yes, I have the license but I have only the app builder and GUI Procedure editor installed. Could you please tell me is it possible to get .r file using it

Comment: See my response below

Comment: You use the COMPILE statement as Mike has shown. There are also some menu options available that will produce r-code. As well as built tools like PCT that can build entire applications.